# Symfony2: How to convert 'Doctrine->getRepository->find' from Entity to Array?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I want to return an \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse with the record information, but I need to pass it as array.

Currently I do:

```
$repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('XxxYyyZzzBundle:Products');
$product = $repositorio->findOneByBarCode($value);
```

But now $product is an Entity containing all what I want, but as Objects. How could I convert them to arrays?

I read somewhere that I need to use "Doctrine\ORM\Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY" but seems 'findOneBy' magic filter does not accept such parameter.

```php
*
* @return object|null The entity instance or NULL if the entity can not be found.
*/
public function findOneBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null)
```

---

Well thanks to dbrumann I got it working, just want to add it the full working example.

Also seems that ->from() requires 2 parameters.

```php
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();  
    $query = $em->createQueryBuilder()  
            ->select('p')  
            ->from('XxxYyyZzzBundle:Products','p')  
            ->where('p.BarCode = :barcode')  
            ->setParameter('barcode', $value)  
            ->getQuery()  
            ;  

    $data = $query->getSingleResult(\Doctrine\ORM\AbstractQuery::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
```

Comment: If you're going to be converting objects to arrays a lot, and want more control over them, check out this library: https://github.com/SamsonIT/DataViewBundle

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you want to change the hydration-mode I recommend using `QueryBuilder`:

```
$query = $em->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select('p')
            ->from('Products', 'p')
            ->where('p.BarCode = :barcode')
            ->setParameter('barcode', $valur)
            ->getQuery()
;
$data = $query->getSingleResult(\Doctrine\ORM\AbstractQuery::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
```

But what would probably be better, is adding a `toArray()`- or `toJson()`-method to your model/entity. This way you don't need additional code for retrieving your entities and you can change your model's data before passing it as JSON, e.g. formatting dates or omitting unnecessary properties.

Comment: Thank you, I'll take the QueryBuilder approach for now, I'll move later to adding such methods if necessity arises. Btw, I guess it's $query->getSingleResult instead of only $q?

Comment: You're right, that's a typo. I'll fix it right away.

Comment: from has to Arguments, the first one is the entity name and the second is the alias. `from('XxxYyyZzzBundle:Products','p')`

Answer (score 5):

Have done this two ways if you are working with a single entity:

```
$hydrator = new \DoctrineModule\Stdlib\Hydrator\DoctrineObject($entityManager);
$entityArray = $hydrator->extract($entity);
```

Last resort, you can just cast to an array like any other PHP object via:

```
$array = (array) $entity
```

NB: This may have unexpected results as you are may be working with doctrine proxy classes, which may also change in later Doctrine versions..

Comment: I tried using this method and for the most part it works, but creates problems when there are any '*Many*' relationships in the entity. In one case it returns a proxy to another entity - no biggie, step through the result and do the same thing. But in another it returns a collection. If the collection is empty, you can't seem to do squat with it without exceptions.

Comment: in the latter case, I'm getting "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()" in the BasicEntityPersister whenever I try to access any methods (toArray(), getValues(), getIterator() even count()) on the collection.

Comment: @Scott I ran into this also building an export to YAML tool.  Some of our entities basically would export the entire client database if you followed all the entity relationships.  These edge cases were resolved by creating Native Queries and using custom ResultSetMaps.  Doctrine is pretty good, but you can get lost in the association wonderland rabbit hole.  TIMTOWTDI

Answer (score 2):

```
Can also be used:
$query = $em->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select('p')
            ->from('Products', 'p')
            ->where('p.BarCode = :barcode')
            ->setParameter('barcode', $valur)
            ->getQuery()
;
$data = $query->getArrayResult();
```